# UUID.randomUUID within ThreadLocal

Tags: java

I am looking at the following method and I am wondering if putting `UUID.randomUUID()` within `ThreadLocal` makes any sense or will not introduce an unintentional overhead:

```
class UUIDUtil {

// TODO: why putting randomUUID into ThreadLocal? Will this avoid contentions?
public static final ThreadLocal<UUID> generator = 
                    ThreadLocal.withInitial(UUID::randomUUID);

}
```

Should I leave `randomUUID` within a `ThreadLocal`? And if so, why?

Does putting UUID in ThreadLocal avoids contention if multiple threads want to generate a UUID at the same time?

Comment: true, I changed the code to make it more clear. The question is about, does it make sense to put a UUID into a ThreadLocal? Would this be better for performance (for example, contention, ..)?

Comment: @mypetlion different threads must always see a new value. The intention of using ThreadLocal is to avoid contention. Another possibility is to add a generatorPool which has predefined UUIDs. But in this case I want to use ThreadLocal instead of a generatorPool. Will UUID not suffer from the same contention issues as SecureRandom?

Comment: @nimo23: You are on a wrong track here! The method that is the argument to `withInitial()` is called  just once per thread, on the first call of `get()`  for the ThreadLocal inside that thread. All subsequent calls to get will return the same value (or you kill the ThreadLocal after each time to `get()` …). And you will not avoid congestion, because the context for `randomUUID()` is the same for each thread, because it is a static method.

Comment: @tquadrat good to know, so then the actual code is wrong. How should I change it to have it work like intented? I want avoid contention if multiple threads need a new UUID at the same time..each thread should care of UUID computation by itself. I dont want to use a Pool here, how can I do that with ThreadLocal?

Comment: Create your own class `UUIDGenerator` that implements `randomUUID()` as a non-static method (for that, copy the code from `UUID.randomUUID()`) and place an instance of that to the ThreadLocal. Make sure that you clean up the ThreadLocal when the Thread dies.

Comment: But as far as I remember UUID does not use a SecureRandom, and therefore the risk for a congestion is marginal. Or use the constructor like this: `UUID( counter.getAndIncrement(), System.getCurrentTimeMillis() )` with counter being a static `AtomicLong` that you initialised at program start with a random number.

Comment: No, the randomUUID uses SecureRandom under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a look to the JavaDoc for ThreadLocal, you will find there some sample code that can be used to give each Thread a unique number (the original thread id will be reused!!).

With your code here, you will give each thread a unique id in the form of a UUID. And that has to be stored inside a ThreadLocal instance …

If that makes sense is a different story, but it can be useful for logging purposes, as it allows you to distinguish the threads more clearly as with the thread id only.

Comment: No your answer is another story. The whole intention of putting UUID in ThreadLocal is to avoid contention if multiple threads want to generate a UUID at the same time. For example, it is good to put SecureRandom into ThreadLocal or within a Pool, but I dont know if UUID will have similiar contention problems to justify the use of ThreadLocal. That's the question.

Comment: @nimo23: You are on a wrong track here! The method that is the argument to `withInitial()` is called just once per thread, on the first call of `get()` for the ThreadLocal inside that thread. All subsequent calls to get will return the same value (or you kill the ThreadLocal after each time to `get()` …). And you will not avoid congestion, because the context for `randomUUID()` is the same for each thread because it is a static method.